# How can I find the index position corresponding to a 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a .stl file, and a .txt file, both files need to read xyz values (aka point coordinates). The coordinate value of the stl file contains the coordinate value of the txt file. How can I find the corresponding position (that is, the index) of each coordinate value in the txt file in the stl file?
This is my .py code:

```
def find_sequence():
    mesh = pv.read("./data/bai--LL-去掉下表面.stl")
    vertex = np.around(np.array(mesh.points), decimals=4)
    data = np.around(read_data("./data/锚定点1.txt", 0, 3), decimals=4)
    index = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(vertex)):
            if np.array_equal(data[i, :], vertex[j, :]):
                index.append(j + 1)
    return index
```

I think there is no problem with my logic, but it doesn't work properly, please help me!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace np.array_equal() with np.allclose(). Because the data has a problem with the number of decimal places
code show as below:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(vertex)):
        if np.allclose(data[i, :], vertex[j, :]):
            index.append(j)
```